# Bootstrap website unrecognizable on IE9 and below

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

as the title says, viewing a website i'm working on in IE9 & below renders it a complete mess but it works fine in IE10/Chrome/FF.

Here's the link: http://goo.gl/3e6i30

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that a Wordpress and bootstrap combination will cause problems on older browsers.

Bootstrap 3 apparantly supports IE8 and up with some exceptions: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers

But combine that with wordpress and who knows what will happen.

The best thing to do is to write up some browser specific stylesheets  to sort the issues out...

Comment: I don't think wordpress is causing any problems since the html/css output is essentially the same as if it was a static HTML page. I'm thinking it's something silly like the style sheet not being loaded but I can't figure it out since I don't have much experience with IE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will fix everything but try removing the trailing commas in this code:

```
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto:true,
    autoStart:true,
    pause:8000,
    speed:1000,
    controls: false, // HERE
});
$('.bxslider-no-pager').bxSlider({
    auto:true,
    autoStart:true,
    pager: false,
    controls: false, // HERE
});
```

As certainly older versions of IE break when they encounter these.

Comment: Unfortunately I was encountering this problem before adding the slider code.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code errors, like your missing `doctype`. That's 99% of the display issues in older IE:

> The DOCTYPE Declaration was not recognized or is missing. This
>   probably means that the Formal Public Identifier contains a spelling
>   error, or that the Declaration is not using correct syntax, or that
>   your document is not using a DOCTYPE Declaration.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  opal-bpm.banksthomas.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//opal-bpm.banksthomas.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.